# Firestore Security Rules: How to access Tokens/Custom Auth Claims

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I tried to have an isAdmin function in my Firestore rules:

```
function isAdmin() {
    return request.auth.token.admin == true;
    // return request.auth.token.claims.admin == true; <--- I also tried
}
```

But when using the simulator I get the error:

> Error: simulator.rules line [35], column [13]. Property admin is undefined on object.

I'm sure this user I'm simulating has the admin token set because I check it on the frontend and there it works just fine.

Why are my rules not valid?

Edit: this is the code I use on the frontend (Angular)

```
  return this.auth.authState.pipe(
    take(1),
    switchMap(async (authState) => {
        if (authState) {
            const token = await authState.getIdTokenResult()
            print(token)  // log below
            if (!token.claims.admin) {
                this.router.navigate(['/auth'])
                return false
            } else {
                return true
            }
        } else {
            this.router.navigate(['/auth'])
            return false
        }
    }),
  )
```

This is the `claims` field when logging the token result:

```
claims:
  admin: true
  auth_time: 1596310796
  email_verified: false
  exp: 1596314396
  firebase: {identities: {…}, sign_in_provider: "password"}
  iat: 1596310796
  sub: "OuoqWiPJNUSm8x5erL0Kh6ybHX93"
  user_id: "OuoqWiPJNUSm8x5erL0Kh6ybHX93"
```

This is how I set the custom claim in the admin sdk

```
  return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(user.uid, {
    admin: true
  })
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show your validation on the frontend so we can see both sides of the system.

Comment: I don't see that the client code you're showing actually illustrates to us that the client is seeing custom claims that match what your rules expect.  We just can't see how it's executing.  Perhaps you could add a log messages that shows the specific value of the custom claims.

Comment: @DougStevenson I'm not sure what exactly you mean by this, what information is missing? The client code illustrates that I can get a `firebase.User` object, when I query the tokens of this user with `getIdTokenResult()` I get an object of wich `token.claims.admin` is true, which shows that this user has a custom claims token `admin` which is set to true.

Comment: Back up a moment - you're showing error output from the simulator, but that may not have anything to do with the way your code runs when access from an actual client app.  Are you asking how to make the simulator work the way you expect?  Or are you asking how to make your client app work correctly?  They're not operating with the same underlying systems.  If you want to ignore what the simulator is saying and focus on the client app, your code sample show illustrate for sure that the client sees custom claims.

Comment: Right now, we see code that *checks* the claims, but we can't see the actual outcome of your program.  If you add a line of code to **log the actual claims**, then show us what the log says, then we will know what your code does.  Until then, we are just guessing.  We don't actually know what your claims look like.

Comment: It would also definitely be helpful if we could see the code that sets the claims.  Any visibility into what you're doing here will help.

Comment: @DougStevenson I just tried the functionality in the actual app and not the simulator and it seems like it works, meaning that I can edit a document as an admin, that should only be possible to be editable for admins. I assumed that when it doesn't work in the simulator, it wouldn't work in the app either. But I still don't understand where the error is coming from. Why is the property `admin` undefined? Is the simulator not capable of simulating custom claims? I authorized myself in the simulator with the uid of an admin.

Comment: I also added some more information, but thats probably not needed anymore

Comment: So, to be clear, is your question just about why the simulator is giving you that message, given that your client code is working as expected?

Comment: @DougStevenson When posting the question, I had the error in the simulator and I thought the issue must be with my rules. Now that my rules work when testing on my app, I would be interested why it wont work on the simulator. So yes, the question is (now) about why the simulator is giving me that message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is happening because the test user account provided by the simulator doesn't provide any custom claims.  There is currently no way to indicate to the simulator that you'd like specific claims attached to a simulated authenticated account.  The simulator only provide limited ability to test rules.  If you'd like to see this improve, please file a feature request with [Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support).

If you would like a more fully-featured way to test your rule, the [Firebase emulator suite](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/test-rules-emulator) will let you write code to provide any custom claims you want to the rule to test locally before deployment.